# ordered map implementation

Tags: java, collections

I'm looking for a Map implementation that iterates over the key-value pairs in the order in which they were added. For example

```
Map orderedMap = // instantiation omitted for obvious reasons :)
orderMap.put(4, "d");
orderMap.put(10, "y");
orderMap.put(2, "b");

for (Map.Entry entry : orderedMap.entrySet()) {
  System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ", " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Will always print

```
4, d
10, y
2, b
```

I'm using Java 5.0.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Do you really need it to be a map ?
It seems you're just trying to use a List.

Comment: I really, definitely, absolutely, certainly want a Map

Comment: I don't understand your "obvious reasons" : the key to your answer lies here. (but you had your answer)

Comment: @Jean - Because if I new which class to instantiate, I'd know the answer to the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's [LinkedHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17476_01/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was already something like this in the JDK, but couldn't remember it's name.

Comment: and for the sake of completeness, the other interesting Map implementation in the JDK is TreeMap, which will return the keys in sorted order (2,4,10 in your case).