# How to get the key and value from hashmap in the order they have been put int map

Tags: java, hashmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ordered map implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3288860/ordered-map-implementation)

I am using the hashmap to store the values as follows -

```
 Map<String,String>         propertyMap=new HashMap<String,String>();


 propertyMap.put("Document Type", dataobject.get("dDocType"));
 propertyMap.put("Document Title", dataobject.get("dDocTitle"));
 propertyMap.put("Revision Label", dataobject.get("dRevLabel"));
 propertyMap.put("Security Group", dataobject.get("dSecurityGroup"));
```

After that i am getting the hashmap key and value in a List

```
 documentProperties = new ArrayList(propertyMap.entrySet());
```

But when i iterate over the List i am not getting the key and values in the order i have put it into the map..

Is there is anyway by which i can get the values in the Order i am putting it into the map.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (*insertion-order*).

By the why, why the need for a separate `ArrayList`? You can directly iterate over `Map.entrySet`:

```
for (final Map.Entry<String, String> entry : propertyMap.entrySet()) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`propertyMap.entrySet()` you get results as `Set`. `Set` is un-ordered.

`new ArrayList(propertyMap.entrySet());` constructs a list with the order you have in Set (which may not be the order you have put into map).

If you are looking for order map, you may use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html)

Here is interesting discussion on this [topic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). For more details Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2889777/difference-between-hashmap-linkedhashmap-and-sortedmap-in-java) question and answer given by Michael

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> m : map.entrySet()){


       // Use m.getKey() to get the Key.
       // Use m.getValue() to get the Value.
}
```